# Haskell Plugins

Tags: haskell, ghc

Im using the plugins library, trying to evaluate the string

```
eval "id :: Test -> Test" ["Data.Test"]
```

where Test is

```
module Data.Test where

import Prelude
import Data.Typeable

data Test = TestRec { testString :: String }
            deriving (Show)

deriving instance Typeable Test
```

I have added Data.Test to exposed modules in my .cabal file and installed the module.

However, when i run the above code I get an error

```
api: /tmp/MXXXXX22793.o: unknown symbol `apizm0zi0zi0_DataziTest_zdfTypeableTest_closure'
```

Any idea why this happens?

GHC version: 7.6.3
plugins version: 1.5.4.0

Edit: I have created a small compiling example of the bug: https://github.com/fabianbergmark/plugins-bug.git

Comment: What happens when you evaluate something more trivial, such as `"undefined :: Test"`?

Comment: It yields the same error. However changing to undefined :: Int successfully compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Plugins is considered broken. Changing to hint (Example in git repository) works flawless

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I didn't even know `hint` existed, I was ready to wrestle for hours with `plugins`.